# How To Find First Date of All MOnths In A Year

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello every One i am trying to get Ist date of All months in A year 
Like  if Curretn year is 2012 and i want to get folowing results from a query
like

```
1-JAN-2012
1-FEB-2012
1-APR-2012
.
.
.
.
.
.
1-DEC-2012
```

Is there any one who can solve my problem thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using pl/sql or is this a standalone query? If standalone, are you using php/java to fire the query?

Comment: I Need only Stand alone query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following. You may want to tweak the date format/timezone

```
select to_date('2012/'||l||'/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
from (select level l from dual connect by level < 13)
```

EDIT: As provided by the op in the comments, the current year needs to be taken rather than hardcoding it. The updated query is

```
SELECT L || '/01/' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') DATESS FROM 
(SELECT LEVEL L FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL < 13)
```

Comment: what about this which will not fix the year for long time to change the query SELECT L || '/01/' || TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') DATESS
  FROM (SELECT     LEVEL L
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 13)

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness - here's a simpler version:

```
select ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'Y'),ROWNUM-1)
from dual connect by level <= 12;
```

Comment: Simplicity always rocks @Jeffrey :-)

Answer (score 3):

A calendar table is easier to use.  Where I work, for example, you'd just run this query.

```
select cal_date
from calendar
where year_of_date = 2012
  and day_of_month = 1;
```

There's a lot to be said for a query being *obvious*.

Comment: +1 for trying to be obvious.  It always amazes me how few people share that goal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use *solely* date functions to get the value for a specific year you can use the following, [also SQL Fiddle'd](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/20160/12):

```
select add_months(trunc(last_day(add_months(trunc(to_date('2011'
                                                         ,'yyyy')
                                                  , 'y')
                                            , -1)
                                 ) + 1
                        )
                 , level - 1) 
  from dual
connect by level <= 12
```

This turns your "year" into a date, truncates that to the 1<sup>st</sup> of January as by default `to_date('2011', 'yyyy')` returns the current date in that year. It then removes a month, taking us to the 1<sup>st</sup> December 2010. Get's the last day of that month, the 31<sup>st</sup> December and adds a day, so back to the 1st of January, but I also do a `connect by level` and add the `level - 1`, i.e. 0 in January to return the correct day.

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't have a `first_day` function, which would make this a lot easier.

It's roughly the same for the current year:

```
select add_months(trunc(last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'y'),-1)) + 1), level - 1) 
  from dual
 connect by level <= 12
```

Comment: Oracle *does* have a "first day" function: first day of the month is `TRUNC(mydate,'MM')`